# Why is my image sequence render using an old version of my animation?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Whenever I try to render my blender animation, I get this weird sequence render and uses an older version of my animation, and just creates junk files.

I'm using JPEG format, rendering into a new folder. I have tried restarting blender, saving then reopening the file, but this didn't fix it. Please help, I need to get this animation rendered so I can make sure everything looks OK from an animated rendered view.

[Here is  the blend file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4w6t0pe40ovgkge/chroma%20crystal.blend)

Comment: We can't say anything without looking at the the file.
Post your blend.

Comment: It sounds like the old sequence has been packed into the file.  I can't post screen grabs on a comment so try this:
go into Video Sequence Editor
Select your JPG track
Display the Properties menu (N on the keyboard).
Near the filename property will be a button labeled "Unpack".  Click that and then use the [Open file] button to locate your updated sequence.
See if that does it.

Answer (score 2):

I think reason you are seeing an old version of your animation is because you have an image loaded into the Video Sequence Editor (VSE), which is overriding the render.

Either remove the image strip with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Erase Strips* from the VSE:

[image]

Or, un-check 'Sequencer' in the 'Post Processing' panel in the 'Render' tab:

[image]