# Rendering stopped updating

Tags: rendering

I have a particular file in which renders are no longer updating according to changes to the model. The render output is far quicker than normal, and the Render Results show several users. Does anyone have suggestions? Thx for any help!

Comment: Have you added any strips on the sequence editor?

Comment: read http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14800/why-is-my-image-sequence-render-using-an-old-version-of-my-animation

Comment: Yep! D'oh!! Thanks a lot, that one had me stumped.