# Old Project reappears when rendering

Tags: rendering

I just downloaded 2.76 and successfully rendered a project yesterday. But today with a different project the Render fails to work correctly. The old (yesterday) project reappears and begins to render.

Wonder if it is a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have anything loaded on the VSE? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14800/why-is-my-image-sequence-render-using-an-old-version-of-my-animation http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering

Comment: Did you save over the startup file??

Comment: Just checked and yes I do. The problem is fixed. Many thanks @cegaton.