# Animation is different when rendered vs in 3D viewport

Tags: rendering, animation

I have animated an object frame by frame but when blender renders it the object starts moving differently. Instead of moving forward it begins swooshing from side to side for a few random frames and then moves correctly. The weirdest part is that when I'm in my 3d viewport everything moves correctly. There are no particles involved, just a few meshes. Has anyone had this problem? Thank you very much

Comment: Please use the [edit] link and add more information about the object in your question. Post images showing your keyframes, curves or dopesheet to understand more about your scene. the fastest way to get help is if you upload your file. Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of the text of your question.

Comment: Do you have any strips in the VSE? see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14800/why-is-my-image-sequence-render-using-an-old-version-of-my-animation