# Blender Cycles camera renders at wrong position/ratio (not keyframes)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, camera

So I made a mistake (object verts) in a recent animation I made and decided to go back and fix the problem, but when I tried to re-render it (using the animation tab) and the same camera I did as before it rendered the object in the wrong position. I checked my keyframes and markers for the camera; of which I have none, and as of me writing this I can't figure out the problem.

I've provided an image demonstrating the issue. The camera is clearly centered (relative to the object) and on the render preview, using that same camera it is also clearly centered. I honestly don't know why this is happening, thanks to anyone who is willing to help me out.

[image: problem in action]

Comment: Do you have any strips on the VSE? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14800/why-is-my-image-sequence-render-using-an-old-version-of-my-animation

Comment: Is it possible you could upload a .blend exhibiting the problem?

Comment: @cegaton I've checked, but no that doesn't seem to be it. -I've experimented with the problem and it seems like something in one of the other layers is causing it. Once I deleted.. whatever it was in the other layers, it began functioning as normal.

Comment: So, problem solved? -I've been trying to find what caused it in the first place, but as of now I can't say..

Comment: For me it was keyframes and your post reminded me of that.