# Blender 2.83 Cycles Not Rendering New Objects

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I added some new objects and changed the HDR rotation in an existing blend file, but whenever I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> I only seem to get a render output of the scene *before* my recent additions and changes.

As the attached image shows, the added items are outlined/selected and visible in all viewport versions including render view and the new HDR position shows correctly.

Some objects are newly created within this file, some are duplicates (not instances) of objects in this file, and others are copied/pasted from other blend files. They are all scattered within several existing collections and render layers that have previously rendered correctly.

- All the visibility and render options are correctly set in the outliner.
- Composite node is set up correctly.
- I've saved/closed/reopened blender and the blend file.
- I've gone through the checklist of all likely causes for objects not showing
  [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)

---

Although I am not a newbie to blender, I have just switched from 2.79 to 2.83 so I'm not sure if there is something new I haven't learnt yet but it seems like this is rendering a cached version of the scene or something and not what is currently there.

[image]

Comment: If you could attach the scene...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a similar question on SE I found the solution. The VSE has a previous image that is over riding the render result....

[Why is my image sequence render using an old version of my animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14800/why-is-my-image-sequence-render-using-an-old-version-of-my-animation)

I solved my problem by unchecking "sequencer" in the "post processing" tab.

Alternatively I could remove the existing images in the VSE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue, like above *Sequencer* was checked but in 2.83 they moved it to the, *Output Properties* tab with the printer looking icon, under the *Post Processing* panel.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where the green screen data was overriding the data from the camera, it worked after unchecking the compositing box in post processing

Comment: Could you illustrate how? Perhaps describe the steps